# Drop Outlier after subsetting the dataset

Tags: r, outliers

I am analysing a dataset and if ound outliers in the original dataset, which i store in an separate object. However i want to repeat the whole analysis with a subset of the original data AND use the same outlier object again. But it appears quite difficult in the case that:

A: The outlier is still in the subset, but replaced. Therefore the row.number has changed an the wrong sample will be dropped.

Here is an example

```
# Test Dataset
set.seed(1234)
test <- data.frame(F1 = gl(5,5, labels=c("A","B","C","D","E")),
                   V1 = rnorm(25,5,2.1))
# add Treatment effect
test <- within(test, V1 <- as.numeric(F1)+V1)

#add outlier
test[14,2] <- 120

# remember outlier
outlier = -14

# Drop Outlier
which(rownames(test[outlier,])==14)
```

> integer(0)

```
# Drop Outlier from subset
test2 <- test[!test$F1=="B",]
which(rownames(test2[outlier,])==14)
```

> 9

Any Ideas how to get the right outlier dropped, after subsetting the dataset?

Comment: Why is outlier set to _minus_ 14 ? `outlier = -14`?

Comment: Why not create a flag for outlier and have a separate `T/F` column identifying outliers: `test$outlier <- test$V1 == 120`?

Comment: I think you're trying to capture the position (row) where the outlier exists. Not the best way. I'd agree that you have to create another column to flag outliers based on the actual values and not their positions.

Comment: @rbm I use _minus_ 14 to delete the outlier . The probelm is in the original R script I use a loop to perform a linear regression model on each of 35 variables in turn and i want to be able to delete another outlier for each variable.  The position of the outlier is stored in a list of outliers then. My solution at the moment is to use test[!rownames(test) == outlier,] instead of test[outlier,]; of course then the _minus_ has to be deleted.